# How to get specific data in JSON result

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Here my JSON result of my "modeles" of car:

```
[
    {
        "idModele":1,
        "modele":"M3",
        "marque":{
            "idMarque":1,
            "marque":"BMW"
        }
    },
    {
        "idModele":2,
        "modele":"RS6",
        "marque":{
            "idMarque":2,
            "marque":"Audi"
        }
    },
    {
        "idModele":3,
        "modele":"C63 AMG",
        "marque":{
            "idMarque":3,
            "marque":"Mercedes"
        }
    },
    {
        "idModele":4,
        "modele":"Clio RS Trophy",
        "marque":{
            "idMarque":4,
            "marque":"Renault"
        }
    },
    {
        "idModele":5,
        "modele":"Scirocco Type R",
        "marque":{
            "idMarque":5,
            "marque":"Volkswagen"
        }
    },
    {
        "idModele":6,
        "modele":"118d",
        "marque":{
            "idMarque":1,
            "marque":"BMW"
        }
    }
]
```

I just want to get the "modeles" that have the "idMarque:1" (BMW) (in my result they have 2 "modeles") but I don't know how to do it.

My backend : API REST with SpringBoot
My frontend : Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the json array is stored in the variable `result`, you may simply:

1. Loop over the json-array.
2. Check each json-object for the desired condition.

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].marque.idMarque === 1) {
        console.log('Found it ', result[i]);
      }
   }
   ```

---

Even simpler:

```
result.filter(e => e.marque.idMarque === 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just for clarification, this is a javascript question. It doesn't matter what your backend or frontend is.

Answering your question, you can filter your result to get only the elements you're seeking:

```
filteredCars = cars.filter(car => car.marque.idMarque === 1)
```

This will filter the cars with `marque.idMarque = 1`.

You can find about the `filter` function on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

You  can get the model having idMarque:1 using filter operator. For  example  you  get the JSON result in  *result* class variable. Then  you can use filter  as follows.

```
let BMWCars = this.result.filter(e => e.marque.idMarque == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a good idea to check, if you have searched object values, so:

```js
let filtered = models
    .filter(item => item.marque && item.marque.idMarque 
    ? item.marque.idMarque === 1 
    : '')
```

In this case, if you did not get error, when marque key is missing from server response.